# How can I add an argument to this query_cls?

Tags: sqlalchemy, tornado

In my tornado application initialization I am creating a session:

```
self.db = scoped_session(sessionmaker(bind=engine, query_cls=CustomQuery))
```

CustomQuery:

```
class CustomQuery(Query):
    def __new__(cls, *args, **kwargs):
        if args and hasattr(cls, "username"):
                return Query(*args, **kwargs).filter_by(username="john")
        else:
            return Query(*args, **kwargs)
```

How can I pass some sort of parameter to the CustomQuery class, so that if a different username is passed it is filtered on that username?

Comment: See [GlobalFilter](https://bitbucket.org/zzzeek/sqlalchemy/wiki/UsageRecipes/GlobalFilter) or [PreFilteredQuery](https://bitbucket.org/zzzeek/sqlalchemy/wiki/UsageRecipes/PreFilteredQuery)  recipe